# UITableViewController.tableView=nil when creating subclass and override loadView()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'am trying to subclass UITableViewController and perform custom view setup via overriding controller's `loadView()` method. I do that because I need `balanceView` on top of the table view and floating circle button at the bottom. I do things like that, because I'll need this "base" controller for group of different it's subclasses later, they all must have this two views, but they'll have completely different tableViews. Everything is loads correctly, but `tableView` property is nil in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`, but tableViews datasource and delegate methods is called successfully! What I am doing wrong? (Maybe I need to subclass `UIViewController` instead?) Here is my code:

This is my UITableViewController subclass loadView:

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let bView = UIView()

    balanceView = BalanceViewSwift()
    balanceView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bView.addSubview(balanceView)

    tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bView.addSubview(tableView)

    balanceView.addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .top, margin: 0)
        .addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .leading, margin: 0)
        .addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .trailing, margin: 0).end()

    tableView.addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .bottom, margin: 0)
        .addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .leading, margin: 0)
        .addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .trailing, margin: 0).end()

    balanceView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    addButtonView = CircleButton()
    addButtonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addButtonView.backgroundColor = .red
    addButtonView.tintColor = .white
    addButtonView.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    addButtonView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BalanceTableViewController.addButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    bView.addSubview(addButtonView)

    addButtonView.addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .bottom, margin: 16).addAnchorToSuperview(anchor: .trailing, margin: 16).end()
    addButtonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addButtonView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    addButtonView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    balanceView.addFundsButtonIsHidden = !balanceViewAddFundsButtonIsVisible
    addButtonView.isHidden = !circleBottomAddButtonIsVisible

    view = bView
}
```

Comment: why are you setting tableview frame to be zero?

Comment: You should definitely extend UIViewController, not UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove **super.loadView()**

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually.
>   If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to
>   the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and
>   should not be shared with any other view controller object. 
>   **Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.**
>   [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview)